# Highchart multicolour areaspline

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to create a line chart in highcharts with multi-colored areas. I have some timed data I'm trying to render that.In my data I have three type of criticality :minor,major,Critical. I want to draw a line area chart (areaspline) which different colour for criticality . It will be single areaspline chart with different colours for data-point area (when value of these data point is above than a defined limit colour of area should be different ).

Any suggestion would be a great help. here is an snapshot what I want to draw https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B13Q_6knq4vCRVkwQ0YyNGFzSFE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Are you okay with doing it with multiple series? I fear doing it any other way will be hard.

Comment: You are right ,but with multiple threshold , I would have to create multiple series dynamically . Means I can't predict exact numbers of threshold points, its dynamic. So if I get threshold 15 times (say), I would have to iterate and fill null value in-place of non-threshold values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use three series for each color separately.

http://jsfiddle.net/sbochan/w23mbjx5/

Example:

```
series: [{
        data: [1,2,3,null,null,null,4,5,6],
        color: 'green'
    }, {
        data: [null,null,null,null,2,8,4],
        color: 'yellow'
    }, {
        color: 'orange',
        data: [null,null,3,3,2]
}]
```

Comment: Note that this gets extra tricky if treshold values are between point values(and the spline doesn't help either). May require additional points.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian ! however I want to achieve this functionality in single series.I am agree with Ondkloss that it could be tricky for intermediate threshold points.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian ! however I want to achieve this functionality in single series. but its great help I was also trying something similar (see fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/7wSuT/3/ ) but my line was ontersecting. Now I am only worried about large number of data-points.My chart could have thousands of point and between those point there could be multiple threshold. To achieve the solution I would have to create multiple series of threshold values and iterate through all data points. Any alternate ?

Comment: Thank you so much Sebastian,its great help for me.